# Accessing XAMPP server from another PC on LAN

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp, lan

I am trying to make a website for our office which we can only access from our local network. Website is functioning on my PC but not on the other PC in the network.

I allowed Apache thought firewall and also created a new inbound rune in firewall to allow all apps to pass thought port 80 and 443.

Also changed lines in apache httpd -

```
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 192.168.2.51:80
Listen 192.168.2.51:80
```

as well as -

```
# Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
# explicitly permit access to web content directories in other 
# <Directory> blocks below.
#
<Directory />
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Also wrote my Ip address IPv4 protocol, enabled every option in network and sharing center and connection is set as private.

Still, I am unable to access the website from the other PC and when I diagnose it says:
"Your computer appears to be correctly configured, but the device detected or resource (192.162.2.51) is not responding.

If anyone could help me, it would be really appreciated, thank you all in advance!

Comment: By the way, I can not access my main PCs shared folders from laptop either, error message: Windows cannot access Desktop-SJN7Q8V. Check the spelling of the name. Otherwise, there might be a problem with your network. To try to identify and resolve network problems, click Diagnose. But I can access folders on my Laptop from main PC.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Your XAMPP Control panel
2. Click on apache > config > Apache (httpd.conf)
3. Search for Listen 80 and replace with Listen 8080
4. After that check your local ip using ipconfig command (cmd console)
5. Search for ServerName localhost:80 and replace with your local ip:8080 (ex.192.168.1.156:8080)
6. After that open apache > config > Apache (httpd-xampp.conf)
7. Search for Alias /phpmyadmin “C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/” AllowOverride AuthConfig Require local Replace with Require all granted ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
8. Go to xampp > config > click on service and port setting and change apache port 8080
9. restart xampp
10. Then hit your ip:8080 (ex.xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8080) from other computer

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this did not work right now and anyways I need to do this at work later and there to run XAMPP as Admin I need to contact other IT's, which I am trying to avoid if it will be possible